# Error processing Instruction 2: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Tags: solana-program, rust, cpi, spl

I am trying to transfer tokens in a PDA and withdraw from that program, deposit works fine but it throws the error when I withdraw.

````
pub fn withdraw_token(
        ctx: Context<TokenPaymentAccounts>,
        bump: u8,
        currency: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let bump = &[bump][..];
        let binding = [&[bump][..]];
        let program_data_account = &mut ctx.accounts.program_data;
        let mint = &ctx.accounts.mint;

        if ctx.accounts.signer.key().ne(&program_data_account.owner) {
            return err!(Error::InvalidAdmin);
        }

                transfer_checked(
                    CpiContext::new(
                        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                        TransferChecked {
                            authority: ctx.accounts.program_pda.to_account_info(),
                            from: ctx.accounts.program_token_account.to_account_info(),
                            to: ctx.accounts.user_token_account.to_account_info(),
                            mint: mint.to_account_info(),
                        },
                    )
                    .with_signer(&binding),
                    program_data_account.total_usdc,
                    mint.decimals,
                )?;

                program_data_account.total_usdc = 0

        Ok(())
    }


#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct TokenPaymentAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [PROGRAM_DATA_SEED, ID.key().as_ref()],
        bump = program_data.bump
    )]
    pub program_data: Account<'info, ProgramData>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = program_pda
    )]
    pub program_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = signer
    )]
    pub user_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK: Program PDA
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [PROGRAM_PDA_SEED],
        bump = bump
    )]
    pub program_pda: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in all seeds when putting together the seeds for a PDA "signature", including `PROGRAM_PDA_SEED`. Try including it in your `binding`, ie:

```
        let binding = [&PROGRAM_PDA_SEED, &[bump][..]];
```